# How to compress images uploaded through ckeditor in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-ckeditor

I'm using ckeidtors RichTextUploadingField for my Django app and I was wondering if there is a way of compressing the image uploaded through ckeditor before storing it in the server.

Comment: In order to do uploads you have to add the uploading views to urls.py. One thing you can do is write your own uploading view that runs image processing on the files and then point to that view instead of the built-in one that comes with django-ckeditor.  There is no simple option to turn on compressing uploaded images (that I'm aware of).